# Windows 10 Schedule power on or Remote Power on

Tags: windows-10

I have a script I want to run on my Windows 10 laptop during the day when I am not home. I shut the lid at night and put the laptop up so the kids dont get it. Is there a way that I can schedule or remotely turn on my PC so that the script can run?

I know that I cannot write a program to start my PC because the PC is not on to run the program. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: So if you are choosing to give me a thumbs down on my questions can you please be more specific as to why? I can't write a program to start from my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't yet tried this myself, but if your PC is completely off then use BIOS settings. If your PC is simply asleep you can use task scheduler (although your power settings must allow for certain tasks to take place).

There's a lot of different methods to do this, as the below articles outline (Wake on Lan, Task Scheduler, BIOS, mouse, keyboard, etcetera). WoL I've tried and failed at every time, which is why I would suggest BIOS settings.

[How to Schedule Computer to turn on Automatically](https://www.windowschimp.com/turn-on-computer-automatically/)

[How Can I Start and Shut Down My Computer Automatically on a Schedule?](https://lifehacker.com/5831504/how-can-i-start-and-shut-down-my-computer-automatically-every-morning)

[Automatically Turn On/Off Computer at Specified Time](https://www.anotherwindowsblog.com/2011/08/automatically-turn-on-off-computer-at-specified-time.html)

[How to Make Any Computer Boot Up or Shut Down on a Schedule](https://www.howtogeek.com/204742/how-to-make-any-computer-boot-up-or-shut-down-on-a-schedule/)